# convert HTML to XHTML

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

I work on a HTML template , I'm trying to convert it to XHTML to be compatible with JSF , but JSF doesnt accept balise like :

```
<a
href="?module=shop&page=index&url_rewrite=&build=&v=v1.9.6&sidebar_type=fusion&skin=style-default" style="background-color: #eb6a5a" class="no-ajaxify"><span class="hide">style-default</span></a>
```

Error:

```
Error Traced[line: 131] The reference to entity "page" must end with the delimiter ';'.
```

What I should add to make it working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the `&` in the href attribute with `&amp;`. You need to use character references in XHTML.